# Create snapshot tables on first day of month with date in tablename - stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create an stored procedure in SQL Server that should check current date: if today is the first day of month then create some tables and include yesterday date in the table name. If today is not the first day of month, then do nothing.

The idea qould be to simply call this stored procedure in a daily SSIS package.

I am struggling with the addition of the "else (do nothing" and adding the previous date to the table name.

Would something like this work? I can't get it to compile...

`DECLARE @d CHAR(10) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1,GETDATE()), 112)`

IF DAY(GETDATE())=1
BEGIN

DECLARE @table1name NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCATENATE('snapshots_db.Table1_',@d);

select  *
into    @table1name
from    sales_db.Table1;

DECLARE @table2name NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCATENATE('snapshots_db.Table2_',@d);

select  *
into    @table2name
from    sales_db.Table2;

END

ELSE
BEGIN

1=1
END

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to be with the logic you are trying to achieve. for the 'ELSE nothing' part, you can just literally do nothing, don't use any code in that section. I formatted your query above so you could check each section clearly.

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(10),
        @table1name NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @table2name NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @d = CONVERT(CHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1,GETDATE()), 112);
SET @table1name = CONCATENATE('snapshots_db.Table1_',@d);
SET @table2name = CONCATENATE('snapshots_db.Table2_',@d);


IF DAY(GETDATE())=1
   BEGIN

      SELECT *
        INTO @table1name
        FROM sales_db.Table1;

      SELECT *
        INTO @table2name
        FROM sales_db.Table2;

   END;
```